# copying data and syncing new data

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, sync

Part of data has been deleted and I have a backup. How can I copy back the data without syncing, and syncing only new data because the internet connection is very slow, and it is taking long time to upload all data again. So please is there any way to copy the backup without syncing, and syncing only the new data that are not in the backup.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: `cp -u` only copies if the source is newer or the destination is missing - is that what you are searching for?

Comment: Or use [`rsync`](http://askubuntu.com/a/2634/158442) which can calculate differences and only send them.

Answer (score 1):

If this refers to your cloud data on Ubuntu One being deleted and wanting to re upload it you cannot. Canonical has discontinued the Ubuntu One cloud storage service.